# "You proposed this change to yesterday" what does that mean?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-proposals, grammatical-correction

I was checking a documentation which I had updated yesterday and I noticed this:

[image: change yesterday]

It says

> You proposed this change to yesterday

The "to" should be removed:

> You proposed this change yesterday

Comment: It seems to me that you've edited the document yesterday which isn't directly final but is changed into a 'proposal' for an edit. If you try to edit again before the proposal is handled, you retract the proposal (and upon saving the new changes create a new proposal)

Comment: Based on the 1st answer, you might want to clarify the title to show this is a bug report, not a question, and that your document wasn't literally titled "yesterday". I also would tag `bug`, not `feature-request`, as things that are clearly errors shouldn't have the air of optionality implied by "request".

Comment: Or maybe the problem is that a word after "to" is missing in the output because it was null in code? "You proposed this change to 'Example' yesterday".

Comment: @GSerg Yes, probably that is the case. [This](http://i.imgur.com/3F95Zg8.png) is how it normally looks.

Comment: @GSerg Good point. But I don't think you can have a topic with no heading, so there is probably a bug somewhere.

Comment: I wish I could propose a change to yesterday (shouldn't have played Xbox so late...)

Comment: `Change rejected - temporal error.`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ya and I shouldn't have played so much Pokemon Go `:D`

Comment: Proposing changes to yesterday is easy; *implementing* changes to yesterday is the tricky part.

Comment: Have you tried proposing one to tomorrow and seeing if it cancels out?

Comment: Maybe I should try that @TimPost `:D`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's been fixed. Let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @JonEricson yes it was fixed.